# Can you use express-session package to manage sessions in a nextjs app?

Tags: session, session-cookies, express-session

Can you use express-session package to manage sessions in a nextjs app or is it purely for express apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes. You can express middleware modules in next-connect and they should work just fine.